# Best approach to avoid multiple check conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming, parameter-passing, purely-functional

In order to write quality code with good readability, I'm adopting [currying functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) approach and making pure helper functions for most of the repetitive code snippets. I just observed that I’m having an existence/type check everywhere in my project to avoid any possible errors like `type of undefined.`

The checks are like:

```
if (param){
 action...
}
```

I'm thinking to create a global helper function that should take two parameters; `param` that need to be checked and the `action function` to perform the action in case the check passes. Something like:

```
function isExist(param, action){
  if (param){
    action();
  }
}
```

This functions is not ideally working for all snippets/cases. How can i make it efficient and globally functional for all cases? Also is this the right approach. If not then what is the best approach that i should follow to achieve my aim here?

**Example**:

```
if (userInput){
  saveToDB(userInput);
}
if (valueFromDB){
  performSomeAction();
}
if (username && password){
  validate(username, password)
}
```

I want all of these checks at different points in my code to be replaced by single helper function to somewhat like:

```
isExist( userInput, saveToDB(userInput) );
isExist( valueFromDB, performSomeAction );
isExist( (username && password), validate(username, password) );
```

In this way we've replaced this 9 lines of code with just three lines. This is what I wanna achieve.

Comment: This pattern is called guard. You should consider an alternative, lazy version that expects functions (aka predicates) instead of conditions as argument and is curried. Than you can just pass in `Array.prototype.every`/`some` for logical conjunction/disjunction.

Comment: @ftor thanks. I didn't get what do you mean by `an alternative, lazy version that expects functions`. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @adi `var checker = p => f => (...args) => p(...args) ? f(...args) : null; var checkNotNull = checker(args => args.every(x => x != null)); var safeAdd = checkNotNull((a, b) => a + b)); safeAdd(3, 1) /* 4 */; safeAdd(null, 2) /* null */;`

Comment: on a side note, generally you want to try to write your code in such a way that you minimize null/undefined checks. If you call f with the result of g with the result of h `f(g(h(args)))` then you only need to check the arguments in h, not f or g. Write simple functions that you only call with known good input and move the null checks to the fringes (user input, ajax data, etc). This is preferable both for performance and readability over using guards/Maybe/Either all over the place.

Comment: Hey @JaredSmith, yes you're right. thanks for the valuable input.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you try to think of a good name for

```
function isExist(param, action){
  if (param){
    action();
  }
}
```

Then I think one good candidate would be `conditionalExecute(condition, codeToExecute)`. Does this kind of work sound familiar? Are you sure you're not just reinventing the if-statement itself?

Maybe I'm missing your point, but I can't personally see the benefit of encapsulating the logic of the if-statement more than it already is.

**Edit**: It should be noted that within the context of Javascript the code

```
if(someVariable){
  // do something
}
```

already reads like "If `someVariable` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (which `undefined` is not) then....

But sure, if you only want to check for existance (a variable not being undefined) I won't argue against you if you say it's preferable to have a named function that makes that clear.

In that case I think it's clearer to only encapsulate the actual existence check (or what ever you want to check), not the conditional nature (because for that we already have the if-statement). So something like

```
function exists(x) {
  return x !== undefined; // or something like that
}
function isNotNull(x) {
  //TODO:
}
```

Then your code would become more explicit and readable, and you could combine the functions if you wanted

```
function neitherUndefinedNorNull(x){
   return exists(x) && isNotNull(x);
}

if(neitherUndefinedNorNull(X)){
  // your "regular" code here
}
```

If the code inside of the if-statement is repeated, then extract that as a function as well.

```
function myRepeatedCode() {
   // do stuff
}

function someAlternativeCondition(x){ 
  // test
}

if(neitherUndefinedNorNull ){
  myRepeatedCode();
} else if(someAlternativeCondition(x)) {
  myRepeatedCode();
}

// OR combine them in the same if-statement
if(neitherUndefinedNorNull(x) || someAlternativeCondition(x)){
  myRepeatedCode();
}
```

**Last edit**:  If you're chasing characters you could even write

```
// because of short-circuiting, myFunc1 and myFunc2 will only
// execute if myCond1 resp myCond2  is true (or truthy).
myCond1(x) && myFunc1(x)
myCond2(y) && myFunc2(y)
```

Comment: It's not about re-inventing if-else condition rather to avoid several if else conditions that are performing some action just after checking if a specific parameter exists. The point is can we write a single helper function to avoid these repetitive if-else conditions?

Comment: @adi I edited with some more details. 

I think if the condition (inside the `()` of `if()` is repeated, then break that out into a named function. 

If the code inside of the if-statements code bloc (the code inside `{ }` )  is repeated, then also break that into named functions. 

What seems unnecessary (to me) is to make some general function that takes both the condition and the code. Because that is what the if-statement already does.

Comment: I've also updated the question with examples, see if this clears you about my aim that i want to achieve here.

Comment: But doesn't your code (with `isExist` instead of repeated if-statements) only **seem** shorter because of formatting of the if-statements? (They have newlines, but those are optional ). In fact they are roughly the same number of characters, with if-statements or with `isExit`.

I've updated my answer with a final suggestion, which I don't necessarily think is making the code better (clearer or more readable), but it does make it shorter. And this kind of pattern (`someCond(x) && someFunction()`) is pretty common in Javascript, so it's at least good to know that it exists.

Comment: I agree that just functioning an if condition that checks for a parameter looks weird but its making my code file much shorter (as in example) that i wanna achieve here. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I hope I didn't sound rude in my answer. It's good to want to improve your own code, but in my experience it's also easy to take an idea too far. (E.g. learn Promises, then use them for **everything**). That's ok, that's one of the ways to learn where certain "rules of thumb" make / doesn't make sense. And of course we don't have to agree on exactly where the rule "less lines of code == better" stops making as much sense.

Did any of the other answers get closer to what you had in mind? I ask so you don't forget to mark one of them as correct (if any of them they are).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152587/discussion-between-adi-and-jonahe).

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect place to use [`Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe):

```js
const enumerable = true;

// data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

const Maybe   = {};
const Nothing = Object.create(Maybe);
const Just    = value => Object.create(Maybe, {value: {enumerable, value}});

// instance Functor Maybe where

Nothing.map = _ => Nothing;
Maybe.map = function (fun) { return Just(fun(this.value)); };

// instance Applicative Maybe where

Maybe.of = Just;
Nothing.ap = _ => Nothing;
Maybe.ap = function (maybe) { return maybe.map(this.value); };

// instance Monad Maybe where

Nothing.chain = _ => Nothing;
Maybe.chain = function (kleisli) { return kleisli(this.value); };
```

`Maybe` <strike>follows the [Fantasy Land Specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land)</strike><sup>[1]</sup>. Using `Maybe` allows you to write code like this:

```js
// userInput :: Maybe Data
// saveToDB  :: Data -> Something
userInput.map(saveToDB); // :: Maybe Something

// valueFromDB       :: Maybe Data
// performSomeAction :: Data -> Maybe Something
valueFromDB.chain(performSomeAction); // :: Maybe Something

// username :: Maybe String
// password :: Maybe Password
// validate :: String -> Password -> Something
Maybe.of(validate).ap(username).ap(password); // :: Maybe Something
```

Anyway, if you're really interested in functional programming then I suggest that you [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I don't agree with the Fantasy Land Specification on [flipping the arguments of `ap`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/issues/50).

Comment: cool answer. you introduced me to some interesting concepts including `Maybe` that I'm gonna explore and `XY Problem`. 

I don't think this is XY problem as I'm open for any better solution. 

My supporting words from question: `is this the right approach. If not then what is the best approach that i should follow to achieve my aim here?`

Comment: Alright, I hear you. I updated my answer. Removed the line about the XY problem. =)

Answer (score 1):

how about this,  it can process the parameters at same time.

```js
function test(a,b,c)
{
    console.log("%s,%s,%s",a,b,c)
}

function check_and_run(param,action){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //turn arguments to array
    args.shift();  //remove param and action
    args.shift(); 
    if(param)
        action.apply(this,args)  
}


check_and_run(1,test,1,2,3)  //this will invoke test(1,2,3)
check_and_run(0,test,1,2,3)  //this will do nothing
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
function conFun(fnCondition, fnCall, defaultResult=undefined) {
  return (...rest) => {
    if( fnCondition(...rest) ) {
      return fnCall(...rest)
    }
    return defaultResult;
  }
}

const add = conFun(
   (...rest) => rest.every(n => typeof n === 'number'),
   (...rest) => rest.reduce((a, n) => a+n), 
   NaN);

add("1", "2"); //=> NaN
add(1, 2);     //=> 3
```

So in your question you might be after the first argument not being undefined:

```
const firstDefined = (v) => typeof v !== 'undefined';
const cSomeFun = conFun(firstDefined, someFun, "");

cSomeFun(); // ==> ""
cSomeFun("test"); // ==> whatever someFun("test") returns
```

If you are just looking to call something based on non undefined arguments you can simply define it like this:

```
function callDefined(fn, ...rest) {
  if( rest.every(firstDefined) ) {
    return fn(...rest)
  }
  return undefined;
}

callDefined( saveToDB.bind(this, userInput), userInput);
callDefined( performSomeAction, valueFromDB);
callDefined( calidate.bind(this, username, password), username, password);
```